# Answering an email regarding recommendation letters

Tags: recommendation-letter

I asked a professor for a recommendation letter last Thursday to apply to a certain grad school program (and others), and she agreed to do it. However, I received an e-mail yesterday from her that said that the deadline is too soon (I completely understand that I was irresponsible), and that she may not complete it in time. What would be a good/diplomatic way to respond? I do not want to give the impression that I'm forcing her to write the recommendation letter for me.

Comment: How soon is the deadline? Tomorrow? Do you have time to find a new recommendation? Would you have had time if she had said no last thursday?

Comment: Friday, although that doesn't change things much. I think I would've had time to find another referee by then, but now it's not feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oy.  [In the future, give people at least a month for this sort of thing] Here's what you can do.  (1) Be very polite and thank her a lot.  (2) Say that you would like her to write a letter and submit it when she gets the chance [perhaps late as needed].  (3) Email the grad department and say you're applying but one of your letters will be late.

Hopefully that works out at some level.  A few things could go wrong with this plan of course, but it's worth a shot.  In any event, be sure to thank the letter writer profusely before and after the fact.  Cards are nice.

Comment: That sounds like great advice, I'll try it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @distlamer - And also do approach someone else, just in case.  Perhaps this particular professor was planning on taking three weeks off right after turning in grades for the semester.